# Printing PDF files in django

Tags: python, django, winapi

I am trying to print PDF files in my website.
The user presses Print, and some PDF files should be printed by a certain printer. (The website is internal and only one printer which is attached to the server through the network will print the files).

I used this code first:

```
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", pdf_file, None, ".", 0)
```

It printed the file when I had tested it on the local host, but when someone tries to print from another computer he gets this error:

> (31, 'ShellExecute', 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.')

Then I tried this way:

```
GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH = "gswin32.exe"
GSPRINT_PATH = "gsprint.exe"

 import win32print

 currentprinter = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

 win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', GSPRINT_PATH,
                                  '-ghostscript "' + GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH + '" -printer "' + currentprinter + '"  "' + pdf_file + '"', '.', 0)
```

It worked from the local host (but the PDF file wasn't printed properly) and got this error from other computers:

> The default printer was not found.

I thought the printing functionality is limited to the server only since it is the only computer attached to the printer and the printing is being done in the backend, but this error gave me an impression that the other computers are trying to connect to the printer!

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not familiar with django, so this may be a dumb question, but where is this code running: the server, or on the user's machine?

Comment: On the server
The user presses Print button on the browser and then a backend code should send the file to the printer